# Is there a way to add rows corresponding to the count of mismatched data in an Excel column?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have two lists in one workbook, with inconsistently formatted corresponding data.

When I encounter a mismatch in a column, I need to add rows (for as many occurrences as the duplicate exists, only in part of the sheet, and then copy and paste that data down until the next item.

What I'm attempting to do.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Scan down the sheet and remember the last row that col E matched to fill in the missing values.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub align()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim iLastRow As Long, iRowE As Long, iRowMatch As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    iLastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    iRowE = 3
    For Each cell In ws.Range("A3:A" & iLastRow)
        'Debug.Print cell.Address

        ' copy unchanged
        cell.Resize(1, 3).Copy cell.Offset(0, 10) ' ABC to KLM
        cell.Copy cell.Offset(0, 14) ' A to 0
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 2).Copy cell.Offset(0, 16) 'BC to QR

        If ws.Cells(iRowE, "E") = cell.Value Then
           iRowMatch = iRowE
           iRowE = iRowE + 1
        End If

        ' copy matched row
        If iRowMatch > 0 Then
           ws.Cells(iRowMatch, "F").Copy cell.Offset(0, 15) ' F to P
        Else
           MsgBox "No initial match for " & cell.Value, vbCritical
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```